# Cloudera support for docker container or Docker support for CM 5 image

Tags: hadoop, docker, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Recently my org is considering Docker. Our group is using cloudera CDH 5.1.2.

1) Does cloudera compatable with Docker container?
2) Is there any known issue related to docker and cloudera combination?

I could not find any topic on docker in this forum.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: From the future: https://github.com/caioquirino/docker-cloudera-quickstart It seems nice, testing it right now

Answer (score 0):

An official answer from Cloudera has been posted [here](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Cloudera-support-for-docker-container/td-p/20272) :

> I read through what docker is, yesterday.  I do not think this has
>   been tested, there are a number of platform virtualization projects in
>   progress, but I did not see this on the list.
>
> Lookt at its intent, it might work but you would definately want to
>   test.  The thing I'm concearned about is the level of effort to
>   normalize between distribution types as there are a large volume of
>   subcomponents that are brought directly into the CDH "Parcel" that are
>   platform specific.
>
> You might be able to get a CM server and agents deployed in a generic
>   way, but then you would want CM to manage the deployment of CDH parcel
>   across the target "cluster" once it was online, rather than
>   abstracting that install as well.

Bottom line is installing Cloudera Manager inside a Docker container does not seem to be an easy route, because CM needs to manage the installation of the other Hadoop components.

Other options include:

- Using Vagrant to create a CDH VM with Cloudera Manager ([Cloudera Documentation Link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-install-a-virtual-apache-hadoop-cluster-with-vagrant-and-cloudera-manager/))
- Managing CDH components manually without cloudera Manager ([Cloudera Documentation Link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_cdh5_install_prereq2.html))